# Java String Format with Scanner Double

Tags: java

In this program the square root of the double `dVar` gets calculated. Everything's fine here.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.printf("Bitte geben sie eine Beliebige Zahl ein, von welcher die Quadratwurzel berechnet werden soll! ");

        //Scanner Funktionen
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(new Scanner(System.in));

        System.out.println(" ");
        double dVar = sc.nextDouble();
        double dSqrt = Math.sqrt(dVar);

        //Frage nach Nachkommastellen

        System.out.println("Bitte geben sie ein, auf wie viele Nachkommastellen die Quadratwurzel von " + dVar + " Berechnet werden soll!");
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        double nKomma = sc2.nextDouble();

        // RIGHT HERE!
        String AusgabedSqrt = String.format("%.5f", dSqrt);
        // RIGHT HERE!

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Die Quadratwurzel von " + dVar + " ist: " + AusgabedSqrt);
    }
}
```

But I also want the user to enter how many decimal places should be calculated.
I entered 5 as a placeholder. I want the `String.format` to only show the amount of decimal places entered in `sc2`.

Comment: In your last line, you're combining successfully strings and variables. Why don't you do the same with the line with `ausgabedSqrt`?

Comment: Note that you are creating an excessive amount of `Scanner` objects. `System.in` is one input stream and you should create only one `Scanner` for reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... I also want the user to enter how many decimal places should be calculated.
> I entered 5 as a placeholder. I want the `String.format` to only show the amount of decimal places entered in `sc2`."*

I would just concatenate the values.

```java
String AusgabedSqrt = "%%.%df".formatted((int) nKomma).formatted(dSqrt);
```

You could also use the *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* class, to assure the decimal is computed.

```java
System.out.printf("Bitte geben sie eine Beliebige Zahl ein, von welcher die Quadratwurzel berechnet werden soll! ");

//Scanner Funktionen
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println(" ");
BigDecimal dVar = sc.nextBigDecimal().setScale(100, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
BigDecimal dSqrt = dVar.sqrt(MathContext.DECIMAL128);

//Frage nach Nachkommastellen

System.out.println("Bitte geben sie ein, auf wie viele Nachkommastellen die Quadratwurzel von %.1f".formatted(dVar) + " Berechnet werden soll!");
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
int nKomma = sc2.nextInt();

// RIGHT HERE!
String AusgabedSqrt = "%%.%df".formatted(nKomma).formatted(dSqrt);
// RIGHT HERE!

System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Die Quadratwurzel von %.1f".formatted(dVar) +
                   " ist: %%.%df".formatted(nKomma).formatted(dSqrt));
```

Here are two example input and outputs.

```
Bitte geben sie eine Beliebige Zahl ein, von welcher die Quadratwurzel berechnet werden soll!  
2
Bitte geben sie ein, auf wie viele Nachkommastellen die Quadratwurzel von 2.0 Berechnet werden soll!
10
 
Die Quadratwurzel von 2.0 ist: 1.4142135624
```

```
Bitte geben sie eine Beliebige Zahl ein, von welcher die Quadratwurzel berechnet werden soll!  
9
Bitte geben sie ein, auf wie viele Nachkommastellen die Quadratwurzel von 9.0 Berechnet werden soll!
5
 
Die Quadratwurzel von 9.0 ist: 3.00000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a String or Integer/int variable (say decimalPlaces) and take its value from the user.

Then, replace `"%.5f"` by `"%." + decimalPlaces + "f"`

You can store this in a String like this:

```
String sf = "%." + decimalPlaces + "f";

String AusgabedSqrt = String.format(sf, dSqrt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user to enter the number of decimal digits, then use it to **create a String** that will be **passed as the format**.

```
    System.out.println("Enter the number of decimal digits you want to round to: ");
    Scanner digitsScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int digits = digitsScanner.nextInt();

    String format = "%." + digits + "f";

    // RIGHT HERE!
    String AusgabedSqrt = String.format(format, dSqrt);
```

[image]

Hope this helps !!